# Catch Ctrl+C / SIGINT and exit multiprocesses gracefully in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, signals

How do I catch a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in multiprocess python program and exit all processes gracefully, I need the solution to work both on unix and windows. I've tried the following:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import signal
import sys

jobs = []

def worker():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
    while(True):
        time.sleep(1.1234)
        print "Working..."

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print 'You pressed Ctrl+C!'
    # for p in jobs:
    #     p.terminate()
    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(50):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

And it's kind of working, but I don't think it's the right solution.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

[The previously accepted solution](//stackoverflow.com/a/11312948/412080) has race conditions and it does not work with `map` and `async` functions.

---

The correct way to handle <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>/`SIGINT` with `multiprocessing.Pool` is to:

1. Make the process ignore `SIGINT` before a process `Pool` is created. This way created child processes inherit `SIGINT` handler.
2. Restore the original `SIGINT` handler in the parent process after a `Pool` has been created.
3. Use `map_async` and `apply_async` instead of blocking `map` and `apply`.
4. Wait on the results with timeout because the default blocking waits to ignore all signals. This is Python bug https://bugs.python.org/issue8296.

---

Putting it together:

```
#!/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function

import multiprocessing
import os
import signal
import time

def run_worker(delay):
    print("In a worker process", os.getpid())
    time.sleep(delay)

def main():
    print("Initializng 2 workers")
    original_sigint_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, original_sigint_handler)
    try:
        print("Starting 2 jobs of 5 seconds each")
        res = pool.map_async(run_worker, [5, 5])
        print("Waiting for results")
        res.get(60) # Without the timeout this blocking call ignores all signals.
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Caught KeyboardInterrupt, terminating workers")
        pool.terminate()
    else:
        print("Normal termination")
        pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As @YakovShklarov noted, there is a window of time between ignoring the signal and unignoring it in the parent process, during which the signal can be lost. Using `pthread_sigmask` instead to temporarily block the delivery of the signal in the parent process would prevent the signal from being lost, however, it is not available in Python-2.

Comment: This answer works in Windows with Python 2.7.11 though a SIGINT throws a long traceback. In 3.5.2 this answer does not work - SIGINT never properly exits. Instead you get `KeyboardInterrupt` and `Process SpawnPoolWorker` messages and tracebacks from the multiprocessing module and you have to kill the spawned processes manually. The accepted answer doesn't exhibit this behavior.

Comment: @MartyMacGyver Only tested this with Python 2.7.x.

Comment: Also works on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) with Python 2.7.11. This really should be the accepted answer.

Comment: seems like you have to use map_async, not map, can anyone allude as to the difference in single handling? (calling .get on the map_async result didn't seem necessary either)

Comment: This answer will ignore a SIGINT which is sent between the two calls to signal(). Besides, are you certain that subprocesses inherit SIG_IGN? Perhaps you could use signal.pthread_sigmask() to block and unblock SIGINT instead, and set SIG_IGN from a pool initializer function.

Comment: @YakovShklarov `pthread_sigmask` would be ideal, however, this API is absent in Python 2. With regards to signal disposition inheritance - look that up, that would be a smart thing to do.

Comment: Oh, you're right. It's implicit in the behavior of fork().

Comment: Which one was the accepted solution first mentioned? This is now the accepted solution.

Comment: This didn't work for me with Python 3.6.1 on Windows 10, KeyboardInterrupt is not caught

Comment: @szx It was not tested in python 3 and neither in Windows.

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there any ways to retrieve something from children when receiving `KeyboardInterrupt` ?

Comment: @Boop I am not sure, one would need to investigate that.

Comment: This solution is not portable as it works only on Unix. Moreover, it would not work if the user sets the `maxtasksperchild` Pool parameter. The newly created processes would inherit the standard `SIGINT` handler again. The [pebble](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pebble) library disables `SIGINT` by default for the user as soon as the new process is created.

Comment: apparently `join()` is non-blocking because I used `join` before the `get()` **without** delay and it still worked fine! Thanks for the solution

Comment: Note that the blocking calls issue has been resolved in Python 3.3, you can use `map()`, `apply()` and `get()` without a timeout: https://bugs.python.org/issue9205

Comment: @LuperRouch Thanks for the update. I wonder if it was ported to Python 2.

Comment: Nope, 2.7.16 still has the issue.

Comment: I found this pretty confusing until I realized `original_sigint_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)` should be `original_sigint_handler = signal.getsignal(signal.SIGINT)`.

Comment: Also worth noting that `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)` returns the **previous configured signal**.

Answer (score 39):

The solution is based on [this link](http://noswap.com/blog/python-multiprocessing-keyboardinterrupt/) and [this link](https://github.com/jreese/multiprocessing-keyboardinterrupt/blob/master/example.py) and it solved the problem, I had to moved to `Pool` though:

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import signal
import sys

def init_worker():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

def worker():
    while(True):
        time.sleep(1.1234)
        print "Working..."

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(50, init_worker)
    try:
        for i in range(50):
            pool.apply_async(worker)

        time.sleep(10)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Caught KeyboardInterrupt, terminating workers"
        pool.terminate()
        pool.join()
```

Comment: That's a bit too late: there is a race condition window between `fork()` return in the child process and `signal()` call. The signal must be blocked before forking.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin - the signal is blocked in `init_worker` which is called before the `apply_async` - is that what you're talking about?

Comment: What I mean is that the signal must be blocked before the child process is forked and unblocked after. This way the child inherits the signal mask and has no chance to receive the signal.

Comment: It's not too late at all. Also, init_worker is not called before apply_asyc. What happens, init_worker function (as object) is passed to the Pool object. Then pool.apply_async is called and internally calls the init_worker function right before the child is forked. Not sure though how Pool deals with unblocking the signal.

Comment: This only works because of the time.sleep. If you try to `get()` the results of the `map_async` call instead, the interrupt is delayed until processing is complete.

Comment: This is a wrong answer. Correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35134329/412080

Comment: This answer works in Windows with Python 2.7.11 and 3.5.2.

Comment: `Pool` forks the number of child processes running `init_worker` _first_ and once per child process. This occurs _before_ async applying `worker` functions to one (of the pool made available) child processes. This means the SIG_IGN is applied inside each child process and there is no need for pool to deal with unblocking the signal since it won't affect the parent (@ChrisKoston).  One can verify with `print(os.getpid())` in both init_worker and worker and note each worker pid will have had one init_worker run beforehand in the process with the same pid.

Comment: Sure it works. But it's wrong. From the docs: "each worker process will call initializer(*initargs) when it starts." That's "when", not "before". So: a race condition. Here's what can happen: The subprocess is created, but before signal.signal() completes, SIGINT is sent! The subprocess aborts with an uncaught KeyboardInterrupt. This is rare but there are no guarantees it won't happen. (Actually it might not be so rare if you're spawning tons of workers.) If you don't block, the worst thing that could happen would seem to be just crud on your terminal. Still, this is bad practice.

Comment: If you get problem while been blocked by calling `get()`, try to add `while not p.ready():  time.sleep(10)` before it.

Answer (score 15):

Just handle KeyboardInterrupt-SystemExit exceptions in your worker process:

```
def worker():
    while(True):
        try:
            msg = self.msg_queue.get()
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
            print("Exiting...")
            break
```

Comment: For signals that make Python raise SystemExit, this indeed works, on Python 3.6, too. I wonder though, what signals does that include? I would guess SIGKILL and SIGTERM ...?

Comment: You can easily check which signals that includes and the answer is: I think none. SystemExit is only raised by sys.exit according to the docs. Just execute `try:  time.sleep(60) except BaseException as e: print(e)` and you'll see if a specific signal is caught (ime only SIGINT). That's what the manpage states, too.

Comment: @Petri It's probably just SIGINT.  I believe SIGKILL is uncatchable, and SIGTERM is something else.