# Send SIGINT to Python subprocess using os.kill as if pressing Ctrl+C

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing

Using python 3.4 on windows.
I am trying to terminate a child processing simulating a person pressing Ctrl+C (Ctrl+D on linux).

I just added the handler to check if the signal was being handled at all. [I used the idea from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312525/catch-ctrlc-and-exit-multiprocesses-gracefully-in-python)

The objective is to catch the KeyboardInterrupt (SIGINT), and release the resources. But it seems that the exception is not thrown if SIGINT doesnt come from the keyboard.   That's why I created an handler, but the process doesnt seem to run the handler at all...

```
import multiprocessing
import time
import signal
import signal
import os
import sys

def handler(signal, frame):
    print("handler!!!")
    sys.exit(10)

def worker(): 
    p = multiprocessing.current_process()
    try:
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,handler)  
        print("[PID:{}] acquiring resources".format(p.pid))
        while(True):           
            #working...
            time.sleep(0.5)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        pass
    finally:
        print("[PID:{}] releasing resources".format(p.pid))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lst = []
    for i in range(1):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
        p.start()
        lst.append(p)

    time.sleep(3)      
    for p in lst:        
        os.kill(p.pid,signal.SIGINT)
        p.join()
        print(p)
        print(p.exitcode)
    print("joined all processes")
```

Here is an example of the output:

```
C:\Users\Rui>python test.py
[PID:16524] acquiring resources
<Process(Process-1, stopped[2])>
2
joined all processes
```

- What am I doing wrong?
- Should I use subprocess module?
- What other approaches could I try to interrupt a process execution?

Comment: What kind of work is the real `worker` going to be doing?

Comment: @dano I will use this template for different types of workers. IO/sockets/compressing/network algorithms

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `^C` on Linux, too, since `^D` is `EOT`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not working because you can't use [`os.kill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill) to send arbitrary signals on Windows:

> **`os.kill(pid, sig)`**
>
> Send signal sig to the process pid. Constants for the specific signals
>   available on the host platform are defined in the signal module.
>
> Windows: The `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` and `signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` signals
>   are special signals which can only be sent to console processes which
>   share a common console window, e.g., some subprocesses. **Any other
>   value for `sig` will cause the process to be unconditionally killed by
>   the `TerminateProcess` API, and the exit code will be set to sig**. The
>   Windows version of `kill()` additionally takes process handles to be
>   killed.

The only signals that can be sent via `os.kill` are `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` and `signal.CTRL_BREAK_EVENT`. Anything else just terminates the process, which is what is happening in your case. Using `signal.CTRL_C_EVENT` won't work here, either, because processes started via `multiprocessing.Process` aren't *"console processes which share a common console window"* with the parent. I'm not sure there's much you can do here with signals on Windows; It doesn't look like you're allowed to catch `TerminateProcess` the way you can catch `SIGTERM` on Unix, so you can't do any clean up prior to the process terminating, and you're not using a console application for the child, so `signal.*_EVENT` won't work.

I think your options are: 1) Use the `subprocess` module, and launch the child process with `shell=True`, which I believe will mean `signal.CTRL+C+EVENT` will work. 2) Stick with the `multiprocessing` module, and use a "co-operative" method of interrupting the worker, like [`multiprocessing.Event`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Event).

Comment: I missed that part!! I will then use some kind of lock like `multiprocessing.Event`. the only problem that remains is that it would need to be done after each loop. That is assynchronously.  I think its not possible to throw exceptions inside other processes/threads execution using python. Maybe only using the KeyboardInterrupt mechanism, which is propably implemented in C.

Comment: Yes. But every new process, would create 1 thread that would wait on an event, that another process would set, then that thread would kill the process's main thread.

Comment: @RuiBotelho Ah, gotcha. Yes, I think that will work as long as your main thread is not blocking in a system call at the time you try to raise the exception.