# Could not terminate process when use paramiko for command execution

Tags: python, multiprocessing, paramiko, pool

I have a python script which does remote command execution, and I want to use multiprocessing in it.

I managed to get the program itself working, but when trying to interrupt it using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I get the following exception, and the program doesn't terminate correctly:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
KeyboardInterrupt
Caught KeyboardInterrupt, terminating workers
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Attempted to rewrite question to be easier to understand. Also some formatting

Comment: [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312525/catch-ctrlc-sigint-and-exit-multiprocesses-gracefully-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends a `SIGINT` to the python process, which triggers a [`KeyboardInterrupt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) exception. Here, your parent process hits this exception, and since you are not catching it, it exits brutally, as well as its children.

If you want to handle <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, you need to catch this `KeyboardInterrupt` exception in your parent process. An example is given in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11312948/1836144) for instance. If you share your code we may find something more specific to your case.