# multiprocessing pool stopping after exit of ide

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have been having trouble with exiting Mulitprocessing pool after keyboard interrupt, and after a long time of trying a gave up, but if i just exited CMD after im done/ have done what i needed with my script, what would be the downsides? I know this isn't a good practice, but it dosen't really need to be good. I'm assuming everything gets killed after the Command line is exited, but i'm not sure.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312525/catch-ctrlc-sigint-and-exit-multiprocesses-gracefully-in-python

Basically you need to "notify"/signal the pool with the termination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends. If it is a Python console the ressources might get cleaned up. But I know from software crashes in Python that sometimes the child processes stay alive even when the main application closes. Usually when started directly via the file explorer.

To make sure that your sub threads/process get closed when the main application closes, you shoud set them as daemon. Then killing the main script kills the childs as well.

see this [Link](https://bogotobogo.com/python/Multithread/python_multithreading_Daemon_join_method_threads.php)