# Running Two asyncio Coroutines, Each in its own Python Process

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, coroutine, multiprocess

If we have 2 `asyncio` coroutines, is it possible to use Python `multiproessing` to let each of them run in its own process, **and** allow the coroutines in both processes to be stopped (by calling their `stop` method) when the user hits <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

This will be similar to the code below, except that `foo.start()` and `bar.start()` coroutines should have their own process.

```
from builtins import KeyboardInterrupt
import asyncio
import multiprocessing
import signal

class App:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    async def start(self):
        self.loop_task = asyncio.create_task(self.hello())
        await asyncio.wait([self.loop_task])
        
    async def stop(self):
        self.loop_task.cancel()
        
    async def hello(self):
        while True:
            print(self.text)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo = App('foo')
    bar = App('bar')
    
    # Running in a single process works fine
    try:
        asyncio.run(asyncio.wait([foo.start(), bar.start()]))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        asyncio.run(asyncio.wait([foo.stop(), bar.stop()]))
```

Tried using `multiprocessing` and `signals`, but I am also not sure how to call `foo.stop()` and `bar.stop()` before the 2 processes terminates.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    def init_worker():
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
        
    def start_foo():
        asyncio.run(foo.start())
        
    def start_bar():
        asyncio.run(bar.start())
        
    foo = App('foo')
    bar = App('bar')    
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(10, init_worker)
        
    try:
        print('Starting 2 jobs')
        pool.apply_async(start_foo)
        pool.apply_async(start_bar)

        while True:        
            time.sleep(1)  # is sleeping like this a bad thing?
                
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Caught KeyboardInterrupt, terminating workers')
        pool.terminate()
        pool.join()
    
    print('Shut down complete')

# Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11312948/741099
```

Using Python 3.9.5 on Ubuntu 20.04

---

Based on @Will Da Silva's solution, I made tiny modifications to check if `asyncio.run(app.stop())` gets called on pressing <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>

```
class App:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
    async def start(self):
        self.loop_task = asyncio.create_task(self.hello())
        await asyncio.wait([self.loop_task])
        
    async def stop(self):
        self.loop_task.cancel()
        print(f'Stopping {self.text}')
        
    async def hello(self):
        while True:
            print(self.text)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)

def f(app):
    try:
        asyncio.run(app.start())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        asyncio.run(app.stop())
        
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    
    jobs = (App('foo'), App('bar'))
    with multiprocessing.Pool(min(len(jobs), os.cpu_count())) as pool:        
        try:
            print(f'Starting {len(jobs)} jobs')
            pool.map(f, jobs)
                
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('Caught KeyboardInterrupt, terminating workers')
                
    print('Shut down complete')
```

However, it seems that if I repeat starting and stopping the Python script multiple times, `print(f'Stopping {self.text}')` inside `app.stop()` does not print to stdout half the time.

**Output:**

```
$ python test.py
Starting 2 jobs
bar
foo
^CCaught KeyboardInterrupt, terminating workers
Shut down complete

$ python test.py
Starting 2 jobs
bar
foo
^CCaught KeyboardInterrupt, terminating workers
Stopping bar
Shut down complete

$ python test.py
Starting 2 jobs
foo
bar
^CCaught KeyboardInterrupt, terminating workers
Stopping bar
Stopping foo
Shut down complete
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it without messing with signals, and without changing the `App` class:

```
import asyncio
import multiprocessing
import os


class App:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

    async def start(self):
        self.loop_task = asyncio.create_task(self.hello())
        await asyncio.wait([self.loop_task])
        
    async def stop(self):
        self.loop_task.cancel()
        
    async def hello(self):
        while True:
            print(self.text)
            await asyncio.sleep(2)


def f(text):
    app = App(text)
    try:
        asyncio.run(app.start())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        asyncio.run(app.stop())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = ('foo', 'bar')
    with multiprocessing.Pool(min(len(jobs), os.cpu_count())) as pool:
        try:
            pool.map(f, jobs)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
```

It's important that we limit the number of processes in the pool to `min(len(jobs), os.cpu_count())`, as any unassigned workers won't be in the try-except block that catches `KeyboardInterrupt` when you enter ctrl-c, and so they'll raise an exception.

To avoid this issue completely you could provide the pool with an initializer that ignores `SIGINT`, but that prevents us from catching it with `KeyboardInterrupt` too. I'm not sure how one would ignore it only in the uninitialized worker processes.

You can also create the `App` instances in the parent process, so long as it can be pickled to be passed across the process border into the child processes.

```
def f(app):
    try:
        asyncio.run(app.start())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        asyncio.run(app.stop())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = (App('foo'), App('bar'))
    with multiprocessing.Pool(min(len(jobs), os.cpu_count())) as pool:
        try:
            pool.map(f, jobs)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
```

Comment: Thanks! I gave it a try with a few `print` statements adde and found that the `app.stop()` does not always get called. Original question updated with more details.

Comment: That's strange @Nyxynyx. I tested it with a print statement in `stop`, and found that it was being called. I'll do more testing and see what I can find.

Comment: @Nyxynyx I guess I just got unlucky when running it during my tests earlier. I was able to reproduce the issue, and have fixed it. The solution is to call `close` and then `join` on the pool.